Cryptsetup reports "Not enough space in header json area for new keyslot"
I'm using Almalinux in case that's relevant here.
We use LUKS2 on the local disk, with LVM on top - so /dev/sda1 and 2 are unencrypted, but /dev/sda3 is encrypted and used for the OS.
We also use clevis/tang to do automatic decrypt (and this is working fine).
When we build via kickstart, we set a temporary password when encrypting and building - and then when we have finished the initial build, we use ansible to set good quality passwords in line with our vaulting/security practices.
So that involves a script that does the equivalent of:
cryptsetup luksOpen -S 0 --test-passphrase /dev/sda3 && cryptsetup luksChangeKey -S0 --force-password --batch-mode 

(And of course the 'default' build password is tested for, and replaced with one from our key management system).
This has started failing recently, and I'm a little perplexed as to what might be going wrong.
It definitely works on our initial 'build', which uses a slightly out of date build image, but then we dnf update to the current revision, and now we cannot seem to luksChangeKey or luksAddkey any more.
# Adding new keyslot 2 by passphrase, volume key provided by passphrase (-1).
# Selected keyslot 2.
# Keyslot 0 priority 1 != 2 (required), skipped.
# Keyslot 1 priority 1 != 2 (required), skipped.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 0.
# Running keyslot key derivation.
# Reading keyslot area [0x8000].
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/sda3.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_8:3
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/sda3.
# Device /dev/sda3 READ lock taken.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/sda3
# Device /dev/sda3 READ lock released.
# Verifying key from keyslot 0, digest 0.
# Keyslot 2 assigned to digest 0.
# Trying to allocate LUKS2 keyslot 2.
# Found area 548864 -> 806912
# Running argon2id() benchmark.
# PBKDF benchmark: memory cost = 65536, iterations = 4, threads = 4 (took 72 ms)
# PBKDF benchmark: memory cost = 227555, iterations = 4, threads = 4 (took 264 ms)
# PBKDF benchmark: memory cost = 1048576, iterations = 6, threads = 4 (took 1982 ms)
# Benchmark returns argon2id() 6 iterations, 1048576 memory, 4 threads (for 512-bits key).
# JSON does not fit in the designated area.
# Not enough space in header json area for new keyslot.
# Rolling back in-memory LUKS2 json metadata.
# Releasing crypt device /dev/sda3 context.
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Closing read only fd for /dev/sda3.
Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).

I'm wondering if anyone's able to help me understand what's going wrong here, and thus what I need to do to remedy it.
Is there a 'initial header size' option I can specify on our builds? Or a parameter to cryptsetup? Or am I "just" finding a bug? (But I'm not convinced that something as widely used as cryptsetup is going to have a 'no one can change their passwords' sort of bug)
This is how the LUKs header looks on an example host.
LUKS header information
Version:           2
Epoch:             5
Metadata area:     16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:     16744448 [bytes]
UUID:              
Label:             (no label)
Subsystem:         (no subsystem)
Flags:           (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
    length: (whole device)
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2id
    Time cost:  9
    Memory:     1048576
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha256
    Area offset:32768 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
  1: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      pbkdf2
    Hash:       sha256
    Iterations: 1000
    Salt:       
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha256
    Area offset:290816 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
  0: clevis
    Keyslot:    1
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
    Hash:       sha256
    Iterations: 105025
    Salt:       
    Digest:    

Am I missing something profound? As said, I am certain this works if I don't 'upgrade' the box to a newer kernel, and so my current workaround is to build it, manually re-key it, and then continue to update it, but this seems ... suboptimal.
cryptsetup versions 2.6.0 and 2.7.2
head -c 1M /dev/sda3 | strings -n 128 

reformatted:
{
  "keyslots": {
    "0": {
      "type": "luks2",
      "key_size": 64,
      "af": {
        "type": "luks1",
        "stripes": 4000,
        "hash": "sha256"
      },
      "area": {
        "type": "raw",
        "offset": "32768",
        "size": "258048",
        "encryption": "aes-xts-plain64",
        "key_size": 64
      },
      "kdf": {
        "type": "argon2id",
        "time": 7,
        "memory": 1048576,
        "cpus": 4,
        "salt": "(removed)"
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "type": "luks2",
      "key_size": 64,
      "af": {
        "type": "luks1",
        "stripes": 4000,
        "hash": "sha256"
      },
      "area": {
        "type": "raw",
        "offset": "290816",
        "size": "258048",
        "encryption": "aes-xts-plain64",
        "key_size": 64
      },
      "kdf": {
        "type": "pbkdf2",
        "hash": "sha256",
        "iterations": 1000,
        "salt": "(removed)"
      }
    }
  },
  "tokens": {
    "0": {
      "type": "clevis",
      "keyslots": [
        "1"
      ],
      "jwe": {
        "ciphertext": "(removed)",
        "encrypted_key": "",
        "iv": "(removed)",
        "protected": "",
        "tag": "(removed)"
      }
    }
  },
  "segments": {
    "0": {
      "type": "crypt",
      "offset": "16777216",
      "size": "dynamic",
      "iv_tweak": "0",
      "encryption": "aes-xts-plain64",
      "sector_size": 512
    }
  },
  "digests": {
    "0": {
      "type": "pbkdf2",
      "keyslots": [
        "0",
        "1"
      ],
      "segments": [
        "0"
      ],
      "hash": "sha256",
      "iterations": 88086,
      "salt": "(removed)",
      "digest": "(removed)"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "json_size": "12288",
    "keyslots_size": "16744448"
  }
}

Edit2: The plot thickens: luksHeaderBackup then a restore fails.
But killing 'slot 0' and adding a key works still. (Assuming the 'slot 1' you can extract, but in my cases clevis-luks-pass works well enough)

cryptsetup --version? What does the JSON look like (head -c 1M /dev/luks | strings -n 128)? Does it work without -S0?

Will add to post. Having issues with cryptsetup version 2.7.2, 2.6.0, which is why I suspect it's an error at initial config.

Sorry, can't reproduce it. Report a bug? Or add more debug messages to cryptsetup (full json, size, area instead of "does not fit"). Maybe that would reveal something.

Thanks for trying! I'll try and work through how to get it to reproduce. It seems a workaround of 'delete slot 0, recreate it' will still let us sort of change the password, it just won't let use add a new one.
I have a suspicion it's a sequence problem based on which initrd we use, then which build repo. I'll try doing more debug to it thought too.

For anyone who finds this (and in case anyone's interested) I've logged what I can as an 'issue' with cryptsetup: https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/924 I'll update or answer if/when I've made any further progress on it.

Summarising from my 'issue' report against cryptsetup which may be found here: https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/924
The root of this problem is to do with the default sizing of the LUKS header when creating via Kickstart, and the size of footprint that clevis/tang occupies.
Specifically that when I build these boxes I used the kickstart directive:
part pv.0 --fstype=lvmpv --size=1000 --grow --encrypted --passphrase=DEFAULT_PASSWORD

This applies the defaults for luksFormat (in almalinux, unsure if that's always the default) of 16MB of LUKS header, but 16k - 4k for the JSON metadata area.
This is normally fine, because a luks key slot doesn't have a lot of metadata, so is a sensible default overall.
However we use clevis/tang for unlocking and setup - during the kickstart - a clevis luks bind
We use 6 tang servers - 3 per site - for resilience reasons.
Our kickstart postinstall script includes:
## Below has been manually wrapped for ease of reading

CLEVIS_CFG='{"t":2,"pins":{"tang":[{"url":"http://tang-10.sitea.domain"},
{"url":"http://tang-11.siteb.domain"},
{"url":"http://tang-12.sitea.domain"},
{"url":"http://tang-13.siteb.domain"},
{"url":"http://tang-14.sitea.domain"},
{"url":"http://tang-15.siteb.domain"}]}}'

for device in /dev/sd*[0-9] /dev/nvm*[0-9]
do
   echo checking $device for being LUKS
   cryptsetup isLuks $device
   if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
   then
      echo "$device is LUKS doing clevis sss config"
      clevis luks list -d $device
      echo $DEFAULT_PASSWORD | clevis luks bind -k - -d $device -y -f sss $CLEVIS_CFG
      echo "Final state post clevis:"
      cryptsetup luksDump $device
   fi
done

However we do have 6 tang servers defined for the sss unlock, which might be unusually large. (But was for dual site resilience - we really didn't want to be in a place where our whole enterprise was unable to boot without multiple failures)
The clevis metadata is considerably larger, and adds about 10k to the metadata area, so if we check occupancy:
[root@desktop~]# cryptsetup luksDump --dump-json-metadata /dev/sda3 | jq -c | wc -c
12111

Most of this is in the tokens.0.jwe.protected key, which is around 10k. (In the above post it's snipped for brevity).
E.g.:
[root@desktop ~]# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda3 --dump-json-metadata | jq '.tokens."0".jwe.protected' | wc -c
10849

And compare this with the configured metadata area:
"config":{
    "json_size":"12288",
    "keyslots_size":"16744448"
  }

So we've only got a 'few' bytes free, and this isn't enough for a new key.
This used to work in our 9.1 deployments, because cryptsetup would do in place replacement, and this was the root of my confusion - I can still reproduce a successful luksChangeKey immediately after boot, building on a 9.1 initrd and a 9.2 repo:
# Key change, old slot 0, new slot 0.
# Key slot 0 is going to be overwritten.
# Wiping keyslot 0 area only.

I am unclear why this is  different, as this is cryptsetup 2.6.0 with the same crypt libraries, but in my example above the ChangeKey uses
# Verifying key from keyslot 0, digest 0.
# Keyslot 2 assigned to digest 0.
# Trying to allocate LUKS2 keyslot 2.

And we don't have space for another keyslot, and we never did, because clevis/tang occupies more of the JSON header, and that's why it fails.
Thus the solutions to this problem are:
Reformat the disk with a larger json metadata area.
  --luks2-metadata-size <size>
       This option can be used to enlarge the LUKS2 metadata (JSON)
       area. The size includes 4096 bytes for binary metadata
       (usable JSON area is smaller of the binary area). According
       to LUKS2 specification, only these values are valid: 16, 32,
       64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048 and 4096 kB The <size> can be
       specified with unit suffix (for example 128k).

E.g. the default of 16k means 16k - 4k available, which is what we have.
This would be a destructive option, requiring a backup/restore or rebuild of the disk.
Inconveniently the kickstart part directive doesn't support any of the necessary options to the --encryption flag, so you'd have to do something a little more complicated with your partition creation logic, most likely via a %pre script to select the drives, partition sizing, and pass the required parameters to cryptsetup luksFormat directly.
Dump the header, resize it, and restore it.
Not got a detailed process, but it should be possible to cryptsetup luksDump --dump-volume-key create a new header of the appropriate size with the same settings: encryption parameters (cipher, mode, sector size), LUSK2 device uuid and same data offset - and of course volume key - and then replace the old header with the new.
The cryptsetup-luksDump and cryptsetup-luksFormat manpages are going to be a reference here.
With a HUGE warning that this is a bit ... dangerous, here's what appears to have worked successfully:
cryptsetup luksDump --dump-volume-key --volume-key-file=volkey /dev/sda3 
cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sda3 --header-backup-file=headerbackup.img

## Copy these files to somewhere in case the rest goes wrong. Just bear in mind that someone can use those files to "recover" your system too, so ensure they're handled securely

clevis luks unbind -d /dev/sda3 -s 1 ## may not be necessary
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/luks_test.img bs=1M count=32
losetup -f --show /tmp/luks_test.img 
## This created /dev/loop0, so use that in the next line. 
## note: This NEEDS to have the same block sizes and encryption of sda3
## This works because they used the same defaults each time. 
##NB If you set a different passphrase, it's a bit easier to confirm that you're using the 'new' one not the 'old' one. 
cryptsetup luksFormat --volume-key=volkey --uuid=<UUID OF sda3> --luks-metadata-size=32k --force-password /dev/loop0
cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/loop0 --header-backup-file=new_luks_header.img
cryptsetup luksHeaderRestore /dev/sda3 --header-backup-file=new_luks_header.img
## rerun the clevis luks bind script referenced in my OP to re-apply the clevis-tang config. 

Cross your fingers and reboot, because if you got this wrong you probably just made your system unrecoverable. (I mean, maybe you backed up the volkey/header backup to another device, but bear in mind that's a security risk, so use caution).
Verify success by using luksChangeKey on the temp password you set on the 'new' header, to change it to whatever you would usually use that's more appropriate. (If it booted you know clevis/tang worked).
Just live with two keyslots, and use the clevis decrypt option to change the 'other' key when you need.
clevis-luks-pass -d <devicename> -s 1 

Will extract you the passphrase that clevis generates and uses, so you can use that to do a luksKillSlot followed by a luksAddKey.
This may not always be suitable, but in the scenario above - where our slot 0 luks passphrase is a fallback case for when the clevis/tang mechanism fails, will be workable. You still won't be able to add any more keys though.

So on one hand, the default JSON area provided by LUKS just isn't all that large. And then clevis just puts way too much stuff in there - which I didn't realize, the JSON you posted in your question was short. Surprising that no one else ran into this issue before. It's not mentioned anywhere in clevis documentation that I can see. Are clevis tokens generally that large or is it something special in your case?

We've not done anything unusual I don't think. clevis luks bind -d <dev> -f sss with 6 tang servers defined. The number of servers might be unusually high I guess, but we wanted dual site/multi node resilience. But otherwise it's broadly in line with https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/security_hardening/configuring-automated-unlocking-of-encrypted-volumes-using-policy-based-decryption_security-hardening#deploying-high-availability-nbde-systems_configuring-automated-unlocking-of-encrypted-volumes-using-policy-based-decryption

The 'jwe: Protected' blob is quite a lot of lines, and looks to be about 10k of base64 encoded. So that alone is the hog, but it's also one of the chunks I snipped for brevity, thinking the limit I needed to think about was 16M.
